# Replace content in a property of element?

Tags: jquery, html, replace

Example: I have code like:

```
<a href="#" data-filter='category one'>Category one</a>
```

After replace `space` with `-` I have new HTML

```
<a href="#" data-filter='category-one'>Category one</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, If you want you can move this into any `click` handler

```
 $(function(){
     var datafilter = $('a').attr('data-filter');
     datafilter = datafilter.replace(" ","-");
     $('a').attr('data-filter', datafilter );

 });
```

OR:

```
 $('a').attr('data-filter', $('a').attr('data-filter').replace(" ","-"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
$('a').data('filter', $('a').data('filter').replace(
    'category one', 'category-one'
));
```

To replace all whitespaces with a dash :

```
$('a').data('filter', $('a').data('filter').replace(/ /g, '-'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/